# Subprocess emulate user input after command

Tags: python, command-line, subprocess

I have a script where I used a few command-line tools are utilised. However I've hit an issue where I am trying to convert two videos into one video (which I can do) however this is meant to be an idle process and when I run this command with subprocess.call() it prompted me with a 'A file with this name already exists, would you like to overwrite it [y/n]?' and now I am stuck on how to emulate a users input of 'y' + Enter.

It could be a case of running it as admin (somehow) or using pipes or this Stdout stuff I read about but didn't really understand. How would you guys approach this? What do you think the best technique?

Cheers guys, any help is immensely appreciated!

Comment: What tool are you using to merge the videos? ffmpeg? Most command line utilities have a flag (often `-y`) to automatically answer yes to all such questions.

Comment: I'd advice you to read about Pipes and Stdout stuff again, then come back again and ask about what you *specifically* do not understand. Currently the question is somewhat too broad.

Comment: Yes I am using FFMPEG! Is this wonderful feature apart of it?

Comment: @kazemakase I read it and didn't quite understand, and this led me to believe it might not be the tool for the job. If someone tells me it is what I want for the job then I will go back and read on it until I clock it.

Comment: @J.Scull well, if the `-y` flag does not work for you, you should definitely read it again :)

Comment: @kazemakase Ah I see! I will do, thank you. I'm only a few months into python so you might see me crop up under stdout tag haha.

Comment: @languitar perfect, thank you.

Comment: I've added this as an answer. Would be nice if this was accepted then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often, tools you are calling have a `-y` flag to automatically answer surch questions with yes.